# Passing locale to sort strings alphabetically

Tags: java, kotlin, collator

I have a list of strings that I would like to sort alphabetically, depending on the user's locale. To do this I use Collator:

```
val collator = Collator.getInstance()
return collator.compare(stringOne, stringTwo)
```

By default, Locale.getDefault() is passed to the collator, but I would like to use sorting by locale, which we will receive from the user, with the transfer of language and country. For example:

```
val col2 = Collator.getInstance(Locale("en", "US"))
```

or

```
val col2 = Collator.getInstance(Locale("en", "EN"))
```

Comment: what is the issue you're facing when using `Collator`?

Comment: @mandy8055 The problem is that there are countries that can speak another language (not their native one), such as “Brazil” speaks “Portuguese”, but there are differences from “pure Portuguese”. In connection with such an emphasis, it is precisely necessary to substitute “language” and “country”.

Comment: @СергейБеляков, one way which I can think of is you can use some collection(a `map` perhaps) to store the official language for each country. After that once you get the user's locale, you can check in the collection to see if the user's country has a different official language or not.

Comment: If you want to distinguish from “pure Portuguese”, study the [`Locale` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to learn about variants and extensions. Recent versions of Java use by default the Unicode [*Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) which is rich with data about sub-cultures and variations.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you've already written, which already uses a locale with values taken from the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you just need a way to pass the locale to your `Collator`.You'll need a `Locale` instance to get the job done. Something like:

```kotlin
import java.text.Collator
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val list = ArrayList<String>()
    list.add("árbol")
    list.add("único")
    list.add("cosas")
    list.add("fútbol")

    val spanishLocale = Locale("es", "ES")
    val collator = Collator.getInstance(spanishLocale)

    // Sort the list using the Collator instance
    Collections.sort(list, collator)

    println(list)
}
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://pl.kotl.in/Fky47CxzI)***

You can read more around this in ***[this blog post.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sort-list-alphabetically#sorting-list-with-accented-characters)***

Comment: I would like to somehow receive, through getLocale() or other functions, the current language and country of the user for transmission to this function.

Comment: There are a lot of languages ​​in the world, I can’t write them all down like that. Maybe someone uses, for example, the “language” on the device - Portuguese, and their “country” is Spain

Comment: @СергейБеляков, one way which I can think of is you can use some collection(a `map` perhaps) to store the **official language** for each country. After that once you get the user's locale, you can check in the collection to see if the user's country has a different official language or not.